# Access the most recent year in a python dictionary

Tags: python, dictionary

I have a python dictionary which looks like this:

```py
test_dict = {'id': '00000001',
             '2017': {'some_info': 'toast'},
             '2018': {'some_more_info': 'bread'},
                       }
```

I want to access the most recent year but the most recent year could change every time.

I have tried converting each key to an integer if it is possible ('id' obviously won't convert to an integer) using:

```py
new_d = {}
for k,v in test_dict.items():
    try:
        new_d[int(k)] = v

    except ValueError:
        new_d[k] = v
```

Then tried to find the max key:

```py
max(new_d, key=int)
```

But I still have the error:
`ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: '_id'` which makes sense.

I want to search the dictionary for the max value key for all keys which are integers.

In this example I want to access the 2018 nested dictionary.

Comment: You method will work if you just create the new dictionary with numerical keys i.e just use "pass" when in ValueError exception.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is one approach using `max` with custom key.

**Ex:**

```
test_dict = {'id': '00000001',
             '2017': {'some_info': 'toast'},
             '2018': {'some_more_info': 'bread'},
            }

print(max(test_dict.items(), key=lambda x: int(x[0]) if x[0].isdigit() else False))
#or
print(max(test_dict, key=lambda x: int(x) if x.isdigit() else False))
```

**Output:**

```
('2018', {'some_more_info': 'bread'})
2018
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that `'id'` is the only non-numerical value, you can use the fact that `max` works as expected on strings as long as you only pass 4-digit years:

```py
test_dict[max(x for x in test_dict if x != 'id')]
```

or if you like Python's functional programming primitives,

```py
test_dict[max(filter(partial(str.__ne__, 'id'), test_dict))]
```

Alternatively, in your given example, the value of interest is the last one. If you can assume that this is always the case, you can make use of the fact that Python dictionaries are ordered (since Python 3.7) and just do

```py
list(test_dict.items())[-1]
```

Comment: it's better if we add `if x.isdigit()` insead of `x!='id'`

Comment: Given the assumption that `'id'` is the only non-numerical value, you'd get the same result.

Answer (score 0):

How about a custom dictionary?

```
from collections import UserDict

class YearDict(UserDict):
    def most_recent(self):
        ints = (key for key in self if key.isdigit())
        return max(ints, key=int)
```

Demo:

```
>>> test_dict = {'id': '00000001', 
...:              '2017': {'some_info': 'toast'}, 
...:              '2018': {'some_more_info': 'bread'}, 
...:            }                                                               
>>>                                                                             
>>> yd = YearDict(test_dict)                                                    
>>> yd.most_recent()                                                            
'2018'
```

Depending on your use case, you might want to add additional methods and a sanity check for when there are no years in the dict.

Also, consider making the keys integers and simplify `most_recent` accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

In the end I came up with this helper function:

```py
def helper_max_year(dictionary_of_comp):
    new_d = {}
    for k,v in dictionary_of_comp.items():
        try:
            new_d[int(k)] = v
        except ValueError:
            new_d[k] = v
    integer_keys = [key for key in new_d.keys() if type(key) == int]
    return (max(integer_keys))
```

Comment: with this approach you can use a number which store maximum year and compare the current year with maximum, if it is less then maxi thne change it

Answer (score 0):

in O(N) time, maintain a variable to save current max year till the present iterator and loop through this

```
test_dict = {'id': '00000001',
             '2017': {'some_info': 'toast'},
             '2018': {'some_more_info': 'bread'},
                       }

def func(data):
    max_year= -10000
    for k, v in data.items():
        if k.isdigit() and int(k)>max_year:
            max_year = int(k)
    return {str(max_year): data[str(max_year)]}


print(func(test_dict))
```

output

```
{'2018': {'some_more_info': 'bread'}}
```